# ¿Como mando props a traves de un Link a un componente en React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Tengo un boton (con un Link dentro) en el cual pretendo enviar una imagen y un titulo, mediante props, y no logro que reciba ninguno de los dos.

-estoy usando React Router V6.8 -

Dejo el codigo aqui:

```html
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

<button className="bg-black text-white w-24 p-1 rounded-xl font-inter text-sm mx-auto my-4">
    <Link
      to={{
        pathname: `/article/${props.title}`,
        aboutProps: {
          img: `${props.img}`,
          title: `${props.title}`,
        },
      }}
    >
      Read more
    </Link>
</button>
```

y esto seria el componente que los recibe:

```html
export default function Article(props) {
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center">
      <div className="w-full">
        <img
          src={props.img}
          className="w-full saturate-100"
        />
        <div className="bg-black text-white bg-opacity-80 h-36 w-6/12 rounded-xl z-30 absolute bottom-10 left-2 flex flex-col gap-1 backdrop-blur-md">
          <h1 className="text-6xl font-bebas pt-2 indent-4 ">
            {props.title}
          </h1>
          <p className="text-base font-inter ml-8 w-10/12">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur                       adipisicing elit. Quae
            consectetur eaque eos.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que usar la propiedad state del link y recuperarla en el location.

```
<Link to="ruta" state={{img: "imagen", title:"titulo"}}>Read more</Link>
```

Y para recuperarlos, en el componente que sea:

```
const location = useLocation();
const {img, title} = location.state;
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias, enserio! estuve un rato buscando en distintas fuentes como hacer y no encontraba, gracias. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

para acceder a los atributos que necesitas tienes que buscarlos dentro del atributo location de en los props que recibe tu componente. En tu codigo te faltaria nada mas obtener los atributos asi:

```
const { img, title } = props.location.aboutProps;
```

Tu código final para el componente quedaria asi:

```
export default function Article(props) {
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center">
      <div className="w-full">
        <img
          src={props.location.aboutProps.img}
          className="w-full saturate-100"
        />
        <div className="bg-black text-white bg-opacity-80 h-36 w-6/12 rounded-xl z-30 absolute bottom-10 left-2 flex flex-col gap-1 backdrop-blur-md">
          <h1 className="text-6xl font-bebas pt-2 indent-4 ">
            {props.location.aboutProps.title}
          </h1>
          <p className="text-base font-inter ml-8 w-10/12">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur                       adipisicing elit. Quae
            consectetur eaque eos.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: aunque lo señalado  no me haya funcionado, te agradezco la ayuda! Intuyo que el problema se debe a mi codigo y no a tu solucion brindada, pero de todas formas ya lo he resuelto, gracias!